# How to use `org-timestamp-up/down` commands?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I'm playing around with org-mode clock commands to see how things work. These commands `org-timestamp-up` and `org-timestamp-down`, don't seem to be working. More likely, I'm not understanding what they are supposed to do.

The docs make it sound to me like if I adjust one end of a time period, the command will also push or pull the adjacent one. But, given this:

```
* Learning Emacs org-mode
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2023-02-07 Tue 12:35]--[2023-02-07 Tue 12:45] =>  0:10
CLOCK: [2023-02-07 Tue 12:20]--[2023-02-07 Tue 12:30] =>  0:10
CLOCK: [2023-02-06 Mon 11:20]--[2023-02-06 Mon 12:20] =>  1:00
:END:
```

I put point on the minutes of `12:30` (second line) and hit `S-M-<UP>`, it moves the time to `12:35`, but nothing else moves. I thought it would shift the start of the next one (`12:35` to `12:40`).

What's an example of using these commands?

Here's what it says in the info docs:

```
‘S-M-<UP>’ (‘org-timestamp-up’)
‘S-M-<DOWN>’ (‘org-timestamp-down’)
     On ‘CLOCK’ log lines, increase/decrease the timestamp at point and
     the one of the previous, or the next, clock timestamp by the same
     duration.  For example, if you hit ‘S-M-<UP>’ to increase a
     clocked-out timestamp by five minutes, then the clocked-in
     timestamp of the next clock is increased by five minutes.
```

Comment: This is a bug (possibly in the doc, probably in the code and quite possibly in both): `S-M-<up>` is bound to `org-shiftmetaup` whose documentation says what the info doc you quote says, but instead of calling `org-clock-timestamps-up`, it calls `org-timestamp-up` which most definitely does *NOT* do what the doc above says it does. Please report it with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: The bug report has been filed!